# about CONCAT query so slow

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:
TABLE A  - 1200000 rows - 14 column

I want to update `TABLE A` with other column value to `TABLE A` "address 1 ","address 2" column,
but when I use the query it's so slow.
 The query time is more than 20 minutes.

```
UPDATE [TABLE A]
    SET `address 1` = CONCAT("Taiwan",`area`,`road`,`lane`,alley,number),
        `address 2` = CONCAT("Taiwan",`area`,`town`,`road`,lane,alley,number);
```

this query is fine. but it's slowly
so I how to optimizer this query ?

I tried to use another query, but thats so slow too.

this picture is address1 column (use CONCAT() other column)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehFNn.jpg)

this picture is other column (CONCAT() this to address1)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VemuH.jpg)

Comment: but this is one-time query, right?

Comment: You update the whole table. There is no any way to optimize it. You may think about not static but generated column usage.

Comment: What does Table B have to do with anything? You could maybe speed it up by exporting the table to a .csv like file, and running a batch job on it, and reloading the data but if it's a one-off job, it's probably not worth the effort or risk.

Comment: @BhargavChudasama yep , i want to update address 1 and address 2 with [TABLE A]

Comment: @Akina okay,I understand ,It a bad news

Comment: @SimonGoater sorry,I modify my question,Just [TABLE A]

Comment: Forgive me for saying this, but it looks like you're trying to do something unwise, with an inadequate skill set, to achieve an end-goal that eludes us all.

Comment: sorry, my english is poor ,but i add some picture to my post thx

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean

```
 UPDATE A
     JOIN B ON ...
     SET A.... = B...?
```

Updating 100K rows takes time.  It will save the old value of each row in case there is a crash.

See this for how to clump the activity into manageable chunks:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Comment: sorry my English is weak,
I  correct my question
Only address 1 and address 2 of table a are to be updated with [TABLE A]

UPDATE [TABLE A]
    SET `address 1` = CONCAT("Taiwan",`area`,`road`,`lane`,alley,number),
        `address 2` = CONCAT("Taiwan",`area`,`town`,`road`,lane,alley,number);

and this query is slow,how dit I optimize it

Comment: If there is no `WHERE` clause, that will change _every_ row.  Is that what you want?

Comment: yes, Because the field data (address1 ,address2) needs to be added to other fields.
maybe there are other ways
Because the reason I need to do this is
Finally, address1 address2 needs to be compared with the fields of TABLE B
If it matches, you will need to add a field value of TABLE B to the field of TABLE A

Comment: Please provide a few sample rows -- both before and after the UPDATE.

Comment: okay,i will edit my post